# $.ajax deferred issue: Object doesn't support property or method 'then'

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, deferred

I'm trying to chain some ajax calls but I'm getting an "Object doesn't support property or method 'then'" error. I'm trying to send a chunk of data in one call, (hopefully) getting a unique value back, then sending that unique value to another call.

Here are my methods...

```
var fetchDocID = function() {   
            log('fetchDocID: ');
            // ajax call
            $.ajax({
                url: myUrl,
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Negotiate");
                },
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                data: '{\"Text\": \"'+myText+'\"}',             
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                    console.log("fetchDocID Error: " + errorMessage);
                }
            });
}   

var fetchSuccess = function(response){
        console.log('fetchSuccess');      
        myDocID = response.documentID;
        console.log("myDocID: "+ myDocID);
        var qryDocID = myNewUrl + myDocID;
        return $.ajax(qryDocID);
}
```

I'm trying to use the following to chain it all together. This is where I'm getting the error...

```
fetchDocID.then(fetchSuccess).then(function(response){
    console.log("fetchDocID: " + JSON.stringify(response));
}).catch(onError);
```

I probably haven't had enough coffee today. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-in-future**. `fetchDocID.then(...)` looks for `then` on the function `fetchDocID`. You want to **call** the function and look for `then` on what it returns: `fetchDocID().then(...)`. In `fetchDocID`, you also want to return the result of calling `$.ajax` (like you did in `fetchSuccess`).

Comment: Yep! You nailed it! Thank you!

Comment: No worries. :-) Best to delete the question (with the "delete" link under it). Happy coding!